# Issues with text parsing, Character looks like a longer 'hyphen' and has 3 ASCII values

Tags: ruby, regex, unicode, ascii, text-parsing

Here is the devilish character `‐`; inspecting it I got 3 ASCII values:

```
ASCII code 226 128 147
```

Now I want to some how use this character in my regular expression.

Comment: They look like 3 devilish integers to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of those is an ASCII value, because the ASCII range is 0 through 127, and nothing higher.  Code point U+2010 HYPHEN in UTF-8 is written with the three byte values you list there, as revealed by:

```
$ perl -CS -e 'print "\x{2010}"' | perl -C0 -ne 'printf "%vd\n",$_'
226.128.144
```

You can get the name and character properties of that code point using [the *uniprops* script](http://training.perl.com/scripts/uniprops):

```
$ uniprops U+2010
U+2010 ‹‐› \N{ HYPHEN }:
    \pP \p{Pd}
    All Any Assigned InGeneralPunctuation Common Zyyy Dash Dash_Punctuation Pd P General_Punctuation Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph GrBase Hyphen Punct Pat_Syn Pattern_Syntax PatSyn Print Punctuation
```

Other common code points with the Unicode `Dash` property include these shown by [the *unichars* script](http://training.perl.com/scripts/unichars):

```
 $ unichars '\p{Dash}'
 -    45 002D HYPHEN-MINUS
 ‐  8208 2010 HYPHEN
 ‑  8209 2011 NON-BREAKING HYPHEN
 ‒  8210 2012 FIGURE DASH
 –  8211 2013 EN DASH
 —  8212 2014 EM DASH
 ―  8213 2015 HORIZONTAL BAR
 ⁓  8275 2053 SWUNG DASH
 ⁻  8315 207B SUPERSCRIPT MINUS
 ₋  8331 208B SUBSCRIPT MINUS
 −  8722 2212 MINUS SIGN
```

Comment: Could you suggest some way by which I can do this in Ruby? Im a newbie :D

Comment: @Shyman: The problem is that you’re treating your input and/or your source code as byte data, but you need to treat them as UTF-8 encoded Unicode characters.  Which of those two do you not know how to do? Make sure you’re using Ruby 1.9 or better, and put `# encoding: UTF-8` at the top of your script to have the script’s source code understood as UTF-8. You probably also need `-KU` on the `#!` line.

Comment: @Shyman: Why don’t you read [this](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_three_default_encodings) about Ruby and encodings?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably Unicode.  The right answer is to use Unicode throughout.   You'll ultimately
get in a lot of trouble if you try to treat Unicode strings as ASCII.

Comment: More accurately, it is probably UTF-8 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8 ), a Unicode encoding designed to look like ASCII (until you encounter a character that does not exist in ASCII).